# how to call selected index changed for select element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i create a select element dynamically using javascript like this code

```
typehtml = '<select id="select"><option value="first">All      </option>';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'web service url',
    data: "web service parameters",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(response) {
        $(response).find('IssueType').each(function() {

            var namei = $(this).find('Name').text();
            var id = $(this).find('Id').text();


            typehtml += '<option value="' + id + '" >' + namei + '</option>';

        });
        typehtml += '</select>';
        document.getElementById("typediv").innerHTML = typehtml;


    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

and i assign the selected index changed for this select element like this

```
$(function() {
    $("#select").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();

    });
});
```

but when i select a value this function does not fire, does any one know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically added elements use `on` event delegation.

```
$(function() {
    $('#typediv').on('change', '#select', function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();

    });
});
```

Comment: Better use `$("#typediv")` instead of `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind a function for element which is not exist on a page, you have to change your code slightly as given below :

```js
typehtml = '<select id="select"><option value="first">All      </option>';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'web service url',
    data: "web service parameters",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(response) {
        $(response).find('IssueType').each(function() {

            var namei = $(this).find('Name').text();
            var id = $(this).find('Id').text();


            typehtml += '<option value="' + id + '" >' + namei + '</option>';

        });
        typehtml += '</select>';
        document.getElementById("typediv").innerHTML = typehtml;
        //here you have to assign the function
      $("#select").change(function() {
         //code goes here..
     });

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```